# Object property sent from HTML input "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, object, undefined

I'm beginner in coding. I've tried to find similar problem on SO but with no proper result.

I'm writting a code where HTML form sends its value to an object's property, then I want to print it in document using `innerHTML` method. I save object in array so then I can manipulate them.

Some problems appears when I add one more dimension to my array (`arr[i][j]` in code below - 2nd dimension will be needed further) - then object's properties change to "undefined" when printed. What should I do to get access to object's properties in array's 2nd dimension (using JS only)? This is my JS code:

```js
var pro = 0;
var ctg = 1;
var arr = new Array(ctg);
arr[0] = new Array(pro)

function AddProduct() {
  var n = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var p = document.getElementById('price').value;
  pro++;
  for (i = arr[0].length; i < pro; i++) {
    arr[0].push([{
      name: n,
      price: p
    }]);
  }
  var content = '';
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j in arr[i]) {
      content += arr[i][j].name + ' price is ' + arr[i][j].price + '<br>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = content;
};
```

and HTML in `body`:

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
<br>
<input type="text" id="price" placeholder="price">
<br>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick=A ddProduct()>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting

`onclick="AddProduct()"`

for

`onclick=A ddProduct()`

at `html`; and add `[0]` at

`content += arr[i][j][0].name + ' price is ' + arr[i][j][0].price + '<br>';`

for

`content += arr[i][j].name + ' price is ' + arr[i][j].price + '<br>';`

as you pushed an array containing an object to `arr` at first `for` loop. To reference the index of the array, use bracket notation to retrieve object at index `0` of array in `arr`

```js
var pro = 0;
var ctg = 1;
var arr = new Array(ctg);
arr[0] = new Array(pro)

function AddProduct() {
  var n = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var p = document.getElementById('price').value;
  pro++;
  for (i = arr[0].length; i < pro; i++) {
    arr[0].push([{
      name: n,
      price: p
    }]);
  }
  var content = '';
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j in arr[i]) {  
      content += arr[i][j][0].name + ' price is ' + arr[i][j][0].price + '<br>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = content;
};
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
<br>
<input type="text" id="price" placeholder="price">
<br>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="AddProduct()">
```